# structure reading C++

Tags: c++, configuration

I have the following problem:
I have a configuration file that consists a description of fields , which I read it and then parse it.  I want to move it into the code to compile it inside.
How would you do that as bug structure ??? or else ?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to do something something like running code from string (like `eval` in many languages, for example)?

Comment: Are you finding something like boost::regex?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't move it into the code, I'd leave the configuration file as a configuration file.

If you really must do this, you can just embed the file as a string resource into the application and use that - that way you'd change only a minimal amount of existing code. The way you do this depends upon your platform.

If thats not feasible (for whatever reason) I'd set up a single configuration class / namespace to contain all the values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what are you exactly asking.

If you are looking for on-the-fly code execution (like `eval()` function in some languages), then there is no such thing in C++. It's not an interpreted language which can be read and executed line-by-line, it needs to be compiled every time code changes. While it technically is possible to write self-changing code, it's probably not worth the effort.